# How to set the location of an owner draw tooltip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

At runtime I create an owner draw tooltip, set in the popup event the size of my tooltip window and in the draw event the text.

```
public void NewLabel(string aText)
{
  ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
  tt.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(tt_Popup);
  tt.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(tt_Draw);

  tt.BackColor = Color.White;
  tt.AutomaticDelay = 100;
  tt.AutoPopDelay = 35000;
  tt.IsBalloon = false;
  tt.OwnerDraw = true;
  tt.SetToolTip(aLabel, sToolTip); 
}

public void tt_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
  e.ToolTipSize = new Size(e.ToolTipSize.Width + 300, e.ToolTipSize.Height + 200);
}

public void tt_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
  e.DrawBackground();
  e.DrawBorder();
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is, if my tooltip draw event is fired by a control at the bottom of my screen, the tooltip is not set in a visual region automaticaly like the standard tooltip does.

Any idea?

Comment: It is a WinForms app on Frameworks 3.5

Answer (score -2):

The tooltip will check its rectangle is on screen and move itself if required during its call to Show, using its existing size. This happens before Popup. The framework does look at your returned tooltipsize, but its used to adjust the width and the height, not to reposition the window should it no longer fit.

I have not tried, but I think you will have to move the popup yourself to ensure it stays on screen.